# Vue pass input value into TD with v-model inside loop

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, v-for

I'm trying to add a value to an input and then pass that value to a `td` directly below it from within my loop. I've tried defining `v-model` as `'value_' + index` or just `index` but none of those seem to work with getting my input to be read and updated in my td.

```
<tr v-for="(row, index) in csvData" v-bind:key="index">
    <td><input type="text" v-model="testing[index]"></td>
    <td>{{ testing[index] }}</td>
<tr>
```

To clarify `<td>{{ testing[index] }}</td>` should use the value from the `v-model` above on the input.

Comment: Do you have `testing[index]` `testing[with all indexes]` already specified in your `data`?

Comment: Here's why you need to specify the index before vue will detect the change.  
https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#Change-Detection-Caveats